# pandas most efficient way to compare dataframe and series

Tags: pandas, compare, series

I have a dataframe of shape `(n, p)` and a series of length `n`

I can compare them with:

`for i in df.keys():
    df[i] > ts`

Is there a way to do it in one line? something like `df > ts`. 
if yes, is it more efficient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you need [`DataFrame.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html):

```
print (df.gt(s, axis=0))
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[7,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  1  4  7  1  5  7
1  2  5  8  3  3  4
2  3  6  9  5  6  3

s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
print (s)
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64

print (df.gt(s, axis=0))
       A     B     C      D     E      F
0  False  True  True  False  True   True
1  False  True  True   True  True   True
2  False  True  True   True  True  False
```

If need another functions for compare:

- [`lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html)
- [`gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.gt.html)
- [`le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.le.html)
- [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html)
- [`ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html)
- [`eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html)

Comment: This seems good. Are double comparison possible?  something like `s<df<S`?

Comment: Hmmm, it is more complicated, but  think this can works `print ((df.gt(s, axis=0)) | (df.lt(s1, axis=0)))`